# reduce repetition of passing many objects through function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am checking user input and on submit I am checking whether or not the input is empty or not. If it is empty I add a class to highlight that the input box is empty by adding a red border. I am running each input box through a method called `app.setInvalidClass.init()` to set the invalid class. Can I reduce this from the repetition as follows

```
app.setInvalidClass.init(!app.validation.email(userEmail), userEmail);
app.setInvalidClass.init(!app.validation.empty(userName), userName);
app.setInvalidClass.init(!app.validation.empty(userLastName), userLastName);
app.setInvalidClass.init(!app.validation.empty(contestName), contestName);
app.setInvalidClass.init(!app.validation.empty(countryName), countryName);
app.setInvalidClass.init(!app.validation.empty(date), date);
app.setInvalidClass.init(!app.validation.empty(month), month);
app.setInvalidClass.init(!app.validation.empty(year), year);
```

Perhaps I could use `Array#every`, or is there a better approach?

```
 $("#entry").submit(function( event ) {
                var userEmail = $("#email"),
                    userName = $("#first_name"),
                    userLastName = $("#last_name"),
                    date = $("#birth_day"),
                    month = $("#birth_month"),
                    year = $("#birth_year"),
                    countryName = $("#country"),
                    privacyCheck = $('#privacy_check');

                if (![date, month, year, countryName, userName, userLastName, userEmail]
                    .every(app.validation.empty) || !app.validation.dateOfBirth(date, month, year) || !app.validation.email(userEmail) || !privacyCheck.is(':checked') ) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    alert("There are errors with your form.");
                    //set invalid class on form elements if errors
                    app.setInvalidClass.init(!app.validation.email(userEmail), userEmail);
                    app.setInvalidClass.init(!app.validation.empty(userName), userName);
                    app.setInvalidClass.init(!app.validation.empty(userLastName), userLastName);
                    app.setInvalidClass.init(!app.validation.empty(contestName), contestName);
                    app.setInvalidClass.init(!app.validation.empty(countryName), countryName);
                    app.setInvalidClass.init(!app.validation.empty(date), date);
                    app.setInvalidClass.init(!app.validation.empty(month), month);
                    app.setInvalidClass.init(!app.validation.empty(year), year);
                    privacyCheck.css({outline: 'red solid thin'})

                } else {
                    alert("You have entered the competition.");
                }      
            });


app.setInvalidClass = {
        init: function (invalidCondition, jQueryObject) {
            if(invalidCondition) {
                jQueryObject.addClass('invalid');
            }
            else {
                jQueryObject.removeClass('invalid');
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Just create an object that shows what input needs what validation (in your case "empty") and then loop over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for the ones that are identical (all the `empty`s), you can use `forEach`:

```
app.setInvalidClass.init(!app.validation.email(userEmail), userEmail);
[userName, userLastName, contestName, countryName, date, month, year].forEach(function(field) {
    app.setInvalidClass.init(!app.validation.empty(field), field);
});
```

---

That said, validation is a rich area and there are libs/frameworks to help, you may want to look at using one rather than reinventing it.

Comment: *(If you see `email` in both `validation` lines above, hit refresh; the one in the loop is/should be `empty`.)*

Comment: i am trying to write the code without relying on a lib/framework. Obviously I am using jQuery here, but don't want to use anything else. Do you think the code is ok, once i implement your change?

Comment: @phantom: There are some other changes you could make. For instance, right now you're checking everything *twice*; instead, just have the same code that's adding/removing the `invalid` class *also* determine whether you prevent the form submission. Also, it looks a lot like you're checking that every field is empty at the outset, which seems backward. Also note that you can toggle a class via `obj.toggleClass(theClass, flag)` rather than `if/else`.

Comment: Great tip on the `obj.toggleClass()`I hate to ask but would you be able to help with combining into one statement as i am struggling to implement this. I am close, but its messy and not covering all the errors :-S perhaps it is better I ask as a new question?

Comment: @phantom: Sure, if I'm around. Make your best attempt at consolidating them, then if you can't solve issues you have with the result, post a question containing that attempt along with your `app.validation` code (so we know what `empty` and such do) and describing any problems you're having with it (doesn't catch the right things, says things are empty when they aren't, etc.). But step through with your debugger first, that usually points up issues. Good luck with it.

Comment: hey @tjcrowder, i didn't have any luck unfortunately. I have posted the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37498714/use-same-code-to-add-remove-class-and-determine-whether-form-can-be-submitted